# Efficient method for finding natural solutions to a linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science

I'm trying to find an algorithm for solving equations of the following form, where $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ are coprime integers, $b$ is an integer and the variables $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ are natural numbers (including 0):

$$
a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\cdots+a_nx_n=b
$$

For my use case, I am interested in solutions where $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ is small.

The naive method would be to try every possible value for $x_1,\cdots,x_n$, starting with values for which $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=0$ (that is, $x_1=\cdots=x_n=0$), and then values for which $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1$, and then values for which $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=2$, et cetera. However, this method is very computationally intensive and it's not possible to know if the equation does *not* have a solution using this method.

Is there a more efficient method or a method to know whether the equation has any solution?

Comment: Computationally, there are a lot of ways under the name of  "Knapsack problem" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: I hope/trust you know that there will always be a solution in integers (since the coefficients are relatively prime) and that for $n-2$ the extended Euclidean algorithm will find them. You can look up lots of this stuff.